# VBA - filter more than one AutoCAD block

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I have recently started coding VBA and I have question about an example I found online. 
the following example is for filtering an AutoCAD block by name.

What do I do if I wish to insert more that one type of block to the selection?

Any help would be deeply apreciated

I have tried

```
grpValue(0) = "testBlock1" & "testBlock2" & "testBlock3"
```

but to no avail.

The example:

```
   Dim sset As AcadSelectionSet 
   Set sset = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add("TestSet2") 

   Dim filterType As Variant 
   Dim filterData As Variant 
   Dim p1(0 To 2) As Double 
   Dim p2(0 To 2) As Double 

   Dim grpCode(0) As Integer 
   grpCode(0) = 2 
   filterType = grpCode 
   Dim grpValue(0) As Variant 
   grpValue(0) = "testBlock" 
   filterData = grpValue 

   sset.Select acSelectionSetAll, p1, p2, filterType, filterData 

   Debug.Print "Entities: " & str(sset.count) 

   sset.Delete 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this in one of two ways:

#### 1. Wildcard Operators

You can exploit the fact that the filter list argument for the `Select` method will accept [wildcard operators](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-E9CDCF5E-0E9F-4072-8A1D-099764B0A19E-htm.html) when comparing string values, and therefore, you can use the comma (`,`) to separate each "pattern", e.g.:

```
grpValue(0) = "testBlock1,testBlock2,testBlock3"
```

Or, if your block names genuinely adhere to the above naming convention, you could use the following equivalent wildcard pattern:

```
grpValue(0) = "testBlock[123]"
```

#### 2. Logical Operators

Alternatively, you can use the [logical operators](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-A1A6DB80-A730-45D1-B035-331F549E9667-htm.html) `<OR` and `OR>` to implement `OR` logic between multiple DXF group 2 entries in the filter list, e.g.:

```
grpCode(0) = -4
grpValue(0) = "<OR"
Dim i As Integer: i = 1
Dim b
For Each b In Split("testBlock1 testBlock2 testBlock3")
    grpCode(i) = 2
    grpValue(i) = b
    i = i + 1
Next b
grpCode(i) = -4
grpValue(i) = "OR>"
```

Comment: woah, answered by Lee Mac himself :D 
Thanks for the [123] tip, may come in handy

Answer (score 0):

found it, really simple

```
grpValue(0) = "testBlock1,testBlock2,testBlock3"
```

Comment: you should also declare grpCode(0) as String in your code. Use the following code `Dim grpCode(0) as String`

Comment: @Gangula `grpCode(0)` is correctly declared as an array containing integer values.